# Datomic not returning the correct "min" result when retrieving entity ID in result tuple

Tags: clojure, datomic

I've got this simple schema and data:

```
(def product-offer-schema
  [{:db/ident :product-offer/product
    :db/valueType :db.type/ref
    :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one}
   {:db/ident :product-offer/vendor
    :db/valueType :db.type/ref
    :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one}
   {:db/ident :product-offer/price
    :db/valueType :db.type/long
    :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one}
   {:db/ident :product-offer/stock-quantity
    :db/valueType :db.type/long
    :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one}
  ])
(d/transact conn product-offer-schema)

(d/transact conn
  [{:db/ident :vendor/Alice}
   {:db/ident :vendor/Bob}
   {:db/ident :product/BunnyBoots}
   {:db/ident :product/Gum}
  ])
(d/transact conn
  [{:product-offer/vendor  :vendor/Alice
    :product-offer/product :product/BunnyBoots
    :product-offer/price   9981 ;; $99.81
    :product-offer/stock-quantity 78
   }

   {:product-offer/vendor  :vendor/Alice
    :product-offer/product :product/Gum
    :product-offer/price   200 ;; $2.00
    :product-offer/stock-quantity 500
   }

   {:product-offer/vendor  :vendor/Bob
    :product-offer/product :product/BunnyBoots
    :product-offer/price   9000 ;; $90.00
    :product-offer/stock-quantity 15
   }
  ])
```

When I retrieve the cheapest bunny boots, only retrieving the price, I get the expected result (9000):

```
(def cheapest-boots-q '[:find (min ?p) .
                        :where
                        [?e :product-offer/product :product/BunnyBoots]
                        [?e :product-offer/price ?p]
                       ])
(d/q cheapest-boots-q db)
;; => 9000
```

However, when I want to get the entity ID along with the price, it gives me the higher-priced boots:

```
(def db (d/db conn))
(def cheapest-boots-q '[:find [?e (min ?p)]
                        :where
                        [?e :product-offer/product :product/BunnyBoots]
                        [?e :product-offer/price ?p]
                       ])
(d/q cheapest-boots-q db)
;; => [17592186045423 9981]
```

I tried adding `:with` but that gives me an error:

```
(def cheapest-boots-q '[:find [?e (min ?p)]
                        :with ?e
                        :where
                        [?e :product-offer/product :product/BunnyBoots]
                        [?e :product-offer/price ?p]
                       ])
(d/q cheapest-boots-q db)
;; => =>  Execution error (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) at datomic.datalog/fn$project (datalog.clj:503).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For what it's worth, the manual (https://docs.datomic.com/cloud/query/query-data-reference.html) says, "Query variables not in aggregate expressions will group the results and appear intact in the result." Also, the examples on that page do not box the find variables in a vector, and :with is clearly defined as not returning the with'd variable. In short, do give the manual a look. I'm not sure it answers your specific question, but it has a lot of stuff that might interest you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a commenter kind of pointed out, `?e` isn't bound in any way to the `(min ?p)` expression, so it's not defined what you'll get there, beyond a product entity id of some sort.

What you actually want to do is unify those values somehow as part of the query, and not perform aggregation on the results, for example:

```clj
(d/q '[:find [?e ?p]
       :where
       [?e :product-offer/product :product/BunnyBoots]
       [?e :product-offer/price ?p]
       [(min ?p)]] 
     db)
```

You can see that the `min` clause is part of the query, and as such will take part in the unification on the result, giving you what you want.